# Em Python, como atribuir o stdout, stdin, e stderr a variáveis , usando o módulo "subprocess" com o console escondido?

Tags: python

Em Python, como atribuir o stdout, stdin, e stderr a variáveis , usando o módulo "subprocess" com o console escondido? Pois antes de empacotar o programa em executável .exe, eu consigo fazer a atribuição normal, mas depois do programa empacotado para exe com o pyinstaller, sem o console do prompt de comando, da erro. Alguém pode me ajudar? Pois com o console aparecendo funciona, mas com o console escondido não, e como meu programa tem interface gráfica eu não quero console aparecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você não pode usar `shell=True` - se você usar o shell, não vai funcionar.

Em seguida, é só criar uma instância da classe secreta e oculta `subprocess.STARTUPINFO`:

```
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = 0 #SW_HIDE para esconder a janela
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info,
)
```

Lembrando que `cmd` tem que ser uma lista, com o programa e os parâmetros, e não uma string, já que você não está usando `shell=True`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Descubri meu erro. Eu só precisava colocar um try/except em cada um.